# django returns none on web page

Tags: python, django

when I run this function in Django my output is none. what is wrong with the news() function?

Code:

```
import feedparser
from django.http import HttpResponse

def news():
    YahooContent = feedparser.parse ("http://news.yahoo.com/rss/")
    for feed in YahooContent.entries:
        print feed.published
        print feed.title
        print feed.link + "\n"
    return

def html(request):
    html = "<html><body> %s </body></html>" % news()
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

Error:
webpage shows None

Comment: I don't know what is the purpose of using Django, if you are trying to be smarter than Django template engine - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

obviously your news() method returns nothing..

The right way should be:

```
def news():
    YahooContent = feedparser.parse ("http://news.yahoo.com/rss/")
    result = ''
    for feed in YahooContent.entries:
        result += feed.published + '\n'
        result += feed.title + '\n'
        result += feed.link + "\n"
    return result

def html(request):
    html = "<html><body> %s </body></html>" % news()
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

Comment: Thank you for the correction. that did fix the problem but the only issue now is that it puts out all str.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo What is the Django way please?

Comment: @AmirNakhostin so what's the problem now?

Comment: In Django, when you want to render HTML, you create a `template` and you pass the `context` to this template. The link to Django documentation of `template engine` is in the comment to the question.

Comment: Yes, you should create a template, formatting the entries as a context, then render it to the template @AmirNakhostin

Comment: @fish_ball the out put on the web is all text and without any structures.

Comment: You must define your `structure` in a html template file yourself, See the tutorials: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial03/ @AmirNakhostin

Answer (score 1):

You are printing the results, not returning them. In fact, the return statement will return `None`, just like all methods that don't have a return statement.

You should build the string in your method itself, like this:

```
def html(request):
    head = '<html><body>'
    foot = '</body></html>'
    entries = []
    for entry in feedparser.parse("http://news.yahoo.com/rss/").entries:
        entries.append('{}<br />{}<br />{}<br />'.format(entry.published,
                                                   entry.title, entry.link))
    return HttpResponse(head+''.join(entries)+foot)
```

---

> Can you explain your code a little bit?

Imagine you have a list of "entries", like this:

```
entries = [a, b, c]
```

Each entry has a `.published`, `.title`, `.link` attribute that you want to print as a list in HTML.

You can do this easily by looping through it and using the print statement:

```
print('<ul>')
for entry in entries:
    print('<li>{0.published} - {0.title} - {0.link}</li>'.format(entry))
print('</ul>')
```

However, what we need here is to send this data to the browser as a HTML response. We can build the HTML string by replacing `print` with a string that we keep adding to, like this:

```
result = '<ul>'
for entry in entries:
    result += '<li>{0.published} - {0.title} - {0.link}</li>'.format(entry)
result += '</ul>'
```

This will work but is [inefficient and slow](http://www.skymind.com/~ocrow/python_string/), it is better to collect the strings in a list, and then join them together. This is what I did in my original answer:

```
result = ['<ul>']
for entry in entries:
    result.append('<li>{0.published} - {0.title} - {0.link}</li>'.format(entry))
result.append('</li>')
```

Then I just joined them all up with a header and a footer, and then combined each individual string in the list with a space, and returned it as the response:

```
 return HttpResponse('<html><body>'+''.join(result)+'</body></html>')
```

Comment: This is the django way if you are doing the tutorial and haven't learned about templates.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid This probably would work but how would you fix my function to return result. 
Your current code are a little too advanced for me to understand lol.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid when you're doing the tutorial then you don't need to ask a question at SO.

Comment: See @fish_ball's answer for that.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Can you explain your code a little bit? Also, is what you wrote is complete function that I can replace mine with?